# Spring Boot Callable - 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, callable

I am using Callable interface inside a Spring Boot Application that sends auth request:

```
public class TestCallable implements Callable<TestDto> {

    TestEntity testEntity;

    public TestCallable(TestEntity testEntity) {
        this.testEntity = testEntity;
    }


    @Override
    public TestDto call() throws Exception {
        String authRequestBody = "{" +
                                    "\"username\": \"" + testEntity.getLogin() + "\"," +
                                    "\"password\": \"" + testEntity.getPassword() + "\"," +
                                    "\"client_id\": \"" + testEntity.getClientId() + "\"," +
                                    "\"client_secret\": \"" + testEntity.getClientSecret() + "\"" +
                                 "}";
        HttpHeaders authHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        authHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        authHeaders.set("Accept", "application/json");
        authHeaders.set("Grant_type", "password");
        HttpEntity<String> authEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(authRequestBody, authHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        TestDto testDto = testDto  = restTemplate.postForObject(testEntity.getEndpoint(), authEntity, TestDto.class);

        return testDto;
    }
}
```

And I'm sending these requests in 4 threads:

```
List<Future<TestDto>>  futuresList = new ArrayList<Future<TestDto>>();
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
for (Integer i=0; i<4; i++) {
    Callable<TestDto> callable = new TestCallable(testEntity);
    Future<TestDto> future = pool.submit(callable);
    futuresList.add(future);
}
```

The issue is that sometimes I get the error "401 Unauthorized: [no body]". For instance, I can receive 4 tokens from 4 callable jobs 5 times and get the error on the 6th attempt.

If I change the number of threads to 2, then I have the error less often. 10 threads fail every time.

And it always works fine in Postman.

How can I understand the cause of the issue?

Comment: do you send exactly the same data all the time and sometimes get an error?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian yes, exactly

Comment: This sounds like a race-condition to me. e.g. by a concurrent modifaction of the testEntity object that is passed to the callable. 
more threads in the pool => faster execution and a higher risk of race-conditions. 
Is the endpoint your own? maybe there are any access restrictions like max per time?!

Comment: Do you modify TestEntity anywhere after you submit everything to the thread pool? Try to declare all fields of TestEntity as final.

Comment: @Indivon The endpoint that I call from Callable is not mine. In the future, I'm going to use the same auth token instead of calling this request every time. If it's the max per time limit, it will be fixed. But I wanted to be sure now.

Comment: As already said: try to make the testEntity immutable. Looks like you are changing the object (login, password ...) somewhere else

Comment: @Indivon Tried to make testEntity as final with the same results. And even tried to hardcode all values that I get from TestEntity.

Comment: @SergeiTonoian see above, seems like it's really some limit

Comment: yep, looks like a rate limit (what makes sense for an authentication endpoint to prevent e.g. brute-force attacks)

Comment: @AntonBuzak looks like an issue with your endpoint, what if you try to send post requests one by one in a single thread?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian One by one it works good, I sent about 50 consistent requests in postman. Thank for your time!

Comment: @AntonBuzak have you found what causes the problem?

Comment: @SergeiTonoian For now I didn't have a chance to contact anyone from tech support of this endpoint. But I almost sure that it is on their side. I just need to update my logic to save tokens and don't send auth requests every time.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
authHeaders.set("Grant_type", "password");
```

to

```
authHeaders.set("Authorization", "password");
```

Comment: @Codemaker I have a similar issue but I cannot fix it. Can you help me if you have any idea about it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843944/spring-boot-microservices-rest-template-401-unauthorized-error

Comment: Sorry @S.N, you have already set the headers and the data there. I couldn't figure out the exact issue in your come. Let me fork it my machine and come back to you.